# How to use both radio buttons and checkboxes in same fieldset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a survey form that generates an email containing the answers provided. The issue I am having is that one question requires a radio button for three choices but then needs to include checkboxes below that may be use to append information to the radio button choice selected. Here is an example of the code I am describing:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="q_planName" id="q_formStatus_title">Choose one of the following headline options:</label>

                <input type="radio" name="q_formStatus" id="q_formStatus_1" onchange="onSelectionChanged(this);"  />
                <label for="q_formStatus_1"Blah 1</label>

                <input type="radio" name="q_formStatus" id="q_formStatus_2" onchange="onSelectionChanged(this);"  />
                <label for="q_formStatus_2">Blah 2</label>

                <input type="radio" name="q_formStatus" id="q_formStatus_3" onchange="onSelectionChanged(this);"  />
                <label for="q_formStatus_3">Blah 3
```

```
                <br/>The following indications may be appended to any headline option:<br/><br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="q_formStatus" id="q_formStatus_4" ;"  />
                <label for="q_formStatus_4">Date of blah required?</label>


                <input type="checkbox" name="q_formStatus" id="q_formStatus_5" ;"  />
                <label for="q_formStatus_5">Blah is non regulated.</label></fieldset>
```

This looks fine in the form but the code that is used to print these results in the email is identifying this question as a radio input so it is storing the answer as a single response rather than an array (ie. it will print Q: questionTitle, A: answerValue instead of Q:questionTitle, A1:answerValue1,A2:answerValue2 etc.)

Note that these questions had to go through an approval process so please don't just suggest separating it into two separate questions or adding a "None of the above selection".

Thanks!

Comment: so the checkboxes only show up if certain radios are checked?  If so then they should be appended as different question parts so for example if your two checkboxes show up if radio 1 is checked, then pass through those checkboxes as `q_formStatus_a`.  Don't just push them all into one massive array - it will be harder to maintain down the line - I would be cursing the developer that came before me if I came across such code

Comment: Well the checkboxes will always show up no matter what radio button is selected, but it is not mandatory that any checkbox is selected while it is mandatory that at least one radio button is selected. If I do pass the checkboxes as a different name, I will have to find a way to reference it within my loop later. Thanks

Comment: And that's my biggest problem.. This is all code that was written by a developer before me so I am having a very hard time understanding his functions :/

Comment: But as one is mandatory and the other isn't, that to me says that they are different questions, they may be linked to each other but in essence, they are different - what about using an array: `q_formStatus[radio]` for radios and `q_formStatus[check][]` for checkboxes (extra brackets at end as it's an array)

Comment: Yes thank you, I actually just ended up splitting them into separate questions but not listed a Question number for the checkboxes so it still looks seamless on the form. Now I am just struggling to find the code to make it so that the checkbox question is not mandatory... it looks like by default every question is mandatory unless I specify otherwise (which I can't figure out)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different names because each field needs to be identified individually by the server.